# What is the justification for having $\vec{n}_1 \cdot \vec{s} \approx -1$ under the paraxial approximation?

Tags: optics, reflection, geometric-optics

I am currently studying the textbook *Introduction to Optical Metrology* by R. S. Sirohi. Section **1.2 Law of Reflection** says the following:

> It is known that the direction of light beam propagation can be changed by reflection as well as by refraction. Both of these phenomena have been studied in great detail, and laws of reflection and refraction have been formulated based on the observations. The law of reflection can be stated in two parts:
>
> 1. The angle of reflection is equal to the angle of incidence.
> 2. The incident ray, the normal to the reflecting surface at the point of incidence, and the reflected ray lie in a plane.
>
> Both these parts of the law can be put in vector form as
> $$\vec{n}_2 = \vec{n}_1 - 2(\vec{n}_1 \cdot \vec{s}) \vec{s}, \tag{1.1}$$
> where $\vec{n}_1$, $\vec{n}_2$, and $\vec{s}$ are the unit vectors of the incident ray, the reflected ray, and the normal to the surface. Under paraxial approximations, $\vec{n}_1 \cdot \vec{s} \approx -1$, and hence the law of reflection takes the form $\vec{n}_2 = \vec{n}_1 + 2 \vec{s}$.

What is the justification for having $\vec{n}_1 \cdot \vec{s} \approx -1$  under the paraxial approximation? This isn't clear to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The paraxial approximation is also called the "small angle" approximation. Basically, the angle that the incident ray makes with the axis is small.

In this case, I think the axis is along the same line as the normal of the surface.

Note that $\vec{n_1} \cdot \vec{s} = -1$ when the incident ray hits the surface dead-on, so $\vec{s}$ and $\vec{n_1}$ make an angle of 180° with each other. The paraxial approximation says that the angle between $\vec{n_1}$ and the axis (aligned with $\vec{s}$) is small, so the angle between $\vec{n_1}$ and $\vec{s}$ is approximately 180° still in this regime. Hence $\vec{n_1} \cdot \vec{s} \approx-1$.

Comment: When you say "axis", are you referring to the optical axis? So the optical axis is along the same line as the normal of the surface? See here https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/46/Optical_axis_en.png/600px-Optical_axis_en.png And so, since $\vec{n}_1$ and $\vec{s}$ are unit vectors in the same direction, we have that $\vec{n}_1 \cdot \vec{s} = \vert \vert \vec{n}_1 \vert \vert \vert \vert \vec{s} \vert \vert \cos(\theta_i) \approx 1$?

Comment: Yes, the "axis" is the optical axis - sorry for not being clear. Maybe an image would help for your question: https://groups.csail.mit.edu/graphics/classes/6.837/F98/Lecture18/Normal.gif. The normal points out of the surface. The incident ray approaches the surface, and so points in towards the surface. So they are not parallel, but antiparallel, and point in diametrically opposite directions.

Comment: Ahh, ok, that makes sense. So we then have $$\vec{n}_1 \cdot \vec{s} = \vert \vert \vec{n}_1 \vert \vert \vert \vert \vec{s} \vert \vert \cos(\theta) \approx -1,$$ where $\theta \approx \pi$